# Mozilla Firefox in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS won't load webpages

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

Hello all,

I am running a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Lenovo ideapad 110. When I load Ubuntu, I can connect to the wireless network in my house but when I use Firefox to try to load webpages it only works some of the time. Sometimes I can connect to the internet and do online homework or watch videos, but other times it will try to load a page and then say that the server could not be reached. My wireless card is listed by Windows as RealTek 8821AE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The rtl8821ae wireless device is known to be problematic. However, are you by chance using a DSL connection with your ISP?